# Can I connect a PCIe 2.5" SSD to a regular PCIe 3 slot?

Tags: hardware, ssd, pci-express

I'm looking to upgrade my server's storage. It currently has SATA SSD storage but I would like to add to it an even faster PCIe3 SSD. It's a full tower with a few empty PCIe3 slots but no PCIe3 backplane, the motherboard model is [Supermicro X9DR3-F](http://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/Xeon/C600/X9DR3-F.cfm). 2.5" PCIe SSDs are significantly cheaper than SSDs with PCIe3 card form factor. Is there a way to add a 2.5" PCIe SSD despite this motherboard not having the right disk backplane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are buying U.2 form-factor NVMe SSDs, then you could get something like [this PCI adapter card](http://www.addonics.com/products/ad25nvmpx4.php), which let's you fit a 2.5" NVMe SSD into a PCI-e slot.